# Magento multi-currency w/multiple stores

Tags: php, magento

We've got a Magento store setup with prices in USD. We need to set it up so that people can also buy in CAD.

Problem is CAD prices need to be specific prices, they can't just use the exchange rate and USD.

So I believe we would have to setup multiple stores to do this, correct?

Any help docs or advice on how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot do exchange rates, there's some chance you may be able to use the quantity pricing functionality in Magento to fake what you're trying to do, but essentially you're looking for multiple stores, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically you will need to set up multiple stores, with one store having currency in **USD** & another store having currency in **CAD**.